# вытащить код блока из родителя

Tags: javascript, jquery

у нас есть переменная которая хранит штмл код.тег li с вложенным input.как с помощью jquery вытащить в другую переменную код блока инпут.

```
  var sortM = $("#list-items > li > input");
  sortM.sort(function(a2,a1){
  a1_input = ...
}
```

Comment: var sortM = $("#list-items > li "); ***

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#list-items > li").find("input");
//или
$("#list-items > li").eq(%индекс%).find("input");
```

Про `find()` можно почитать [тут](https://api.jquery.com/find/)